# Непонятки с if constexpr

Tags: c++

Следующий код нормально компилируется

```
#include <string>

void set(bool);

void set(std::string) {
}

int main() {
    if constexpr (false) set(true);
}
```

но, если добавить ветку else

```
#include <string>

void set(bool);

void set(std::string) {
}

int main() {
    if constexpr (false) set(true);
    else set("");
}
```

то получается

```
undefined reference to `set(bool)'
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jirML9

буду благодарен тому, кто может объяснить, почему так происходит или ткнуть меня в правильное место стандарта.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`set("");` в этом примере вызывает перегрузку `void set(bool);` Если заменить `void set(std::string)` на `void set(char const *)`, то второй пример также будет нормально собираться:

> **8.5.1 The if statement [stmt.if]**
> 2 If the if statement is of the form if constexpr , the value of the condition shall be a contextually converted constant expression of type bool (7.7); this form is called a constexpr if statement. If the value of the converted condition is false , the first substatement is a discarded statement, otherwise the second substatement, if present, is a discarded statement. During the instantiation of an enclosing templated entity (13.1), if the condition is not value-dependent after its instantiation, the discarded substatement (if any) is not instantiated. [Note: Odr-uses (6.3) in a discarded statement do not require an entity to be defined. —end note]

Comment: Кусок стандарта совершенно не тот. Вроде он про условие if'а.

Comment: @Qwertiy If the if statement is of the form **if constexpr**, а потом про каждый из двух substatement. Потом там еще и пример соотв. приведен, демонстрирующий что ODR использование в отбрасываемом выражении не требует, чтобы сущность была определена.

Comment: Или же вызвать set(string(""))